# Finding position of li in the list of li

Tags: javascript, html, css

So we have a list of li in a page

```
    <li class="page-list">
      <ol>

        <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2354="2354">2</button></li>
        <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2356="2356">3</button></li>
        <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2358="2358">4</button></li>
        <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2360="2360">5</button></li>
        <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2362="2362">6</button></li>
<li class="active">7</li>
        <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2364="2364">8</button></li>
        <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2366="2366">9</button></li>
        <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2368="2368">10</button></li>
        <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2370="2370">11</button></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
```

Now, I know how to find the the length of all the li inside  `<li class="page-list">` but how can determine the position of the specific li in the list?

For example in the above pasted code, there is an `<li>` which have purposely unaligned. Now I want to determine its position from the given list of li, how can I do it using javascript (Manually if you count, its the 5th in an array)

Comment: Whitespace doesn't matter in HTML, is this for a formatter or...?

Comment: @phix formatter, just to highlight the element whose position i am interested to know through JS

Comment: This is an "it depends on what you're trying to do" question.  Are you trying to select the 6th element in the list? or the element which lacks a data attribute? or the element whose text contents are "7"? or the element with the class "active"?  or do you already have a reference to the element and need to determine its position in the tree (by counting its preceding siblings)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn the parentNode of the element into an array, then find its own index:

```
const el = document.querySelector("li.active");

const elPosition = [...el.parentNode.children].indexOf(el);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, You accidentally put in an extra bracket there. Please fix it and I will mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to use jQuery...

```js
document.querySelector("li.page-list").querySelectorAll("ol li").forEach(function (listItem, index) {
    if (listItem.classList.contains("active"))
        console.log(`And the winner is #${index}!`)
});
```

```html
<li class="page-list">
    <ol>
        <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2354="2354">2</button></li>
        <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2356="2356">3</button></li>
        <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2358="2358">4</button></li>
        <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2360="2360">5</button></li>
        <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2362="2362">6</button></li>
        <li class="active">7</li>
        <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2364="2364">8</button></li>
        <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2366="2366">9</button></li>
        <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2368="2368">10</button></li>
        <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-2370="2370">11</button></li>
    </ol>
</li>
```